# Any Implication Behind the Word Respectable here?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, sentence-meaning

I am reading an article from *1843 magazine* and not sure what the implication is behind one sentence.

This part of the article is about a stolen dog was sold by a thief to another person who bought it for $300. The dog was later found and the original owner then knew more information about the crook. The following is the part in the article.

> de Grazia had picked up information about the crook from court filings and the local rumour mill. All of which may be true – but hey, ***$300 for a seven-year-old dog that de Grazia originally bought for about $1,500 from a “renowned breeder” is pretty respectable***.

I don't know why the writer used the word respectable here. Does the writer mean that $300 is well worth the value of the dog? If so, the owner must think the dog is sold at a good price given its age. But I can sense sarcasm here which could mean $300 is too low compared to $1500. I don't know how I should read the sentence.

Comment: 'Respectable' means a 'decent' or 'good price. Please see [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/respectable) C2. The dog is 7 years old, so obviously would be worth far less than when purchased from the breeder.

Answer (score 1):

This is said rather ironically, because of the criminality.

If you (for example) buy a car for $1000, fix it up  and sell it on for $1500, you have made $500 profit.  If you have spent a week working on the car you might be pleased with such a profit.  You could say

> $500 for a week's work is pretty respectable.

You would mean "It is a good amount of money. It is a fair and pleasing profit."

Here, the thief is getting a good price for a dog. The thief should feel pleased with the amount of money.  It is used rather ironically, since it isn't a *fair* amount of money, because the thief had no right to sell the dog at all.

Comment: If I read this sentence from the thief's perspective, it immediately makes sense to me. I was confused because I couldn't get it why the owner would think her dog was sold at a good price. But for the thief, $300 is indeed pretty respectable.

Comment: Yeah. Price and value are different things.  From the point of view of the owner, the dog may have been invaluable:  a friend and companion, but the price of the dog (what the owner believes e would get if the dog were sold) might be much less.  Perhaps the owner would estimate that they'd get between £200 and £350 if they sold the dog (something they would never do) so £300 seems "pretty respectable".